# Using appsettings.json values in Automapper configuration

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is there a way to get a value from appsettings.json when mapping two objects in Automapper?

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
     public MapperProfile()
     {
          CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
             .ForMember(employeeDto => employeeDto.Picture, employee => employee.MapFrom(employee => $"{someValueFromAppSettings}{employee.Picture}"
     }
}
```

I need to append a path before the picture's name on mapping but I can't seem to figure it out how and whether it is even possible with Automapper.

Comment: The question is unclear because `appsettings.json` isn't a special file, nor is it the only source of config settings. The config middleware loads settings from *all* config sources and only allows access to them through the config middleware. The only way to access the config values is using their section/path through IConfiguration, through the IOptions<> interfaces or binding settings to strongly typed objects

Comment: @squezzi are you trying to load the root folder from settings, then use it to generate employee picture paths? Retrieve the root path *before* mapping any way you want, then use `Path.Combine(root, employee.Picture)` in the mapping to get a correct path. If you bind config settings to a strongly typed object, you can pass that to the mapper profile constructor

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yeah, that solution might work in this case.

Comment: @squezzi any feedback?

Comment: @Ergis Yeah, I will accept your answer as it directly answers my question although I used what Panagiotis Kanavos suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the AutoMapper documentation:

> You can’t inject dependencies into Profile classes.

But there are (at least) 2 ways you can achieve what you want:

---

1. Using [IValueResolver<in TSource, in TDestination, TDestMember>](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html) interface.

```
public class EmployeeDtoPathResolver: IValueResolver<Employee, EmployeeDto, string>
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration
        public CarBrandResolver(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration= configuration;
        }

        public string Resolve(Employee source, EmployeeDto destination, int destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var path = // get the required path from _configuration;
            return $"{path}{source.Picture}"
        }
    }
```

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
     public MapperProfile()
     {
          CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
             .ForMember(employeeDto => employeeDto.Picture, opt => opt.MapFrom<EmployeeDtoPathResolver>()); // Edited this
     }
}
```

---

2. Using [IMappingAction<in TSource, in TDestination>](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Before-and-after-map-actions.html#using-imappingaction) implementations.

It is basically an encapsulation of `Before` and `After` Map Actions into small reusable classes.

```
public class EmployeeDtoAction : IMappingAction<Employee, EmployeeDto>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public EmployeeAction (IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
    }

    public void Process(Employee source, EmployeeDto destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var path =  // get the required path from _configuration;
        destination.Picture = $"{path}{destination.Picture}"
    }
}
```

```
public class MapperProfile : Profile
{
     public MapperProfile()
     {
          CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
             .AfterMap<EmployeeDtoAction>(); // Added this
     }
}
```

Comment: A resolver is a better fit here.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu About being a 'better' fit I leave that to you to back it up. This is just one way.

Comment: That's the very purspose of a resolver, a mapping action is just an escape hatch, when nothing else fits.